# What is the correct process for creating a token based API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, token

I have an SPA frontend using React and a backend in Ruby on Rails.

I am using [react-google-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) to get a JWT (JSON-Web-Token) for the user on the frontend. The user clicks the provided login button and, if successful, it returns a JWT. Would the process for interaction with the API go as follows?

Step five is where I need some technical guidance or advice.

1. [Frontend] Get JWT from Google
2. [Frontend] Store JWT in cookie
3. [Frontend] Send JWT with each request to the API
4. [API] Decode JWT to get user information
5. [API] How would I verify that this user information is correct? Should I have a data store of users and verify their info against that? Just check if the name in the token matches the name of a user?
6. [API] If JWT is valid, send data from request

Comment: I have edited to be a bit more clear to avoid the close requests. I am not really sure how else I could ask this question. It is pretty exact in my opinion.

Comment: No need to save the token. this is the avantage of tokens. Fire and forget. if the token verifies, hasn't been tampered.Anyway it's a bad idea to store sensible information inside the token. Everybody can see it, only the verification part is really ciphered, the rest is simply Base64encoded